# jQuery Refreshing image after new file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm having trouble refreshing an image on a page after uploading. I'm posting the multipart image to a hidden iframe. Then I use a javascript callback to change the original image. It works sometimes but not always.

It's not a caching problem as I've tried appending to the URL without effect. It's also consistent between Chrome and Firefox so I don't suspect the browser.

In all cases, if I refresh the whole page, it's correct.

If I inspect the element with Chrome, it seems to show the image as an array? Can someone please explain whats going on?

Thanks

Upload servlet ends with (within iframe):

```
<script>parent.changeImage('/cdn/orig/prof-1.gif')</script>
```

Which calls:

```
function changeImage(image){
    $("#store-image").attr('src', '');
    var ts = new Date().getTime();
    $("#store-image").attr('src', image+"?"+ts);                
}
```

Then after a few loads, Chrome inspection shows:

```
Frames
    file.jsp
        images
            image-1.gif
            image-1.gif
            image-1.gif
            image-1.gif
            image-1.gif
```

Each has a different thumbnail beside it.

Why is the javascript building an array?

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the image name each time you upload? The problem you are facing, is simply the tip of the iceberg really. Web servers do cache static content and it takes time before this cache is refreshed. Some browsers cache statiic content pretty persistently. Some caching proxies do the same thing.

If you are not willing to change the file name, at least add some incrementing parameter to the img src. Like myimage.gif?1235698

Answer (score 0):

Might have solved it...

On the server side, I was relying on overwriting the old file with the same file name. I think due to a lag in the filesystem, the browser was sometimes able to grab the old file before the new one was available - even though the wrote was complete as far as the program was concerned.

I changed the code to delete the old one first, then the server writes the new file with the same name. This seems to stop the browser from grabbing the old one and it instead waits for the new one to come down. Chrome no longer lists the file several times either...

We'll see.

Comment: I would do @Jani suggests if you are doing it that way.  Forces a browser refresh. Kind of like putting a new CSS file up an using a myCSS.css?version=v2.  But if you are relying on server side than everytime you upload a new one with the same name clear the cache on the server for that item.